# wxpython html2 webview not displaying images

Tags: python, html, wxpython

im trying to display an image of type png  using wx.python html2 and by SetPage method but it does not work..i mean the image is not show on screen ..here is the full code..

```
`#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx 
import wx.html2

HTML_CODE=     '''
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
h1 {color:red}
h4 {color:blue;background-color:yellow;text-align:right
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<img src="smile.png" />
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<b><h4>A paragraph.</h4></b>
</body>
</html>          '''


app = wx.App()
fr=wx.Frame(None,-1)
browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(fr,size=(460,400))
browser.SetPage(HTML_CODE,'simple test')
fr.Show() 
app.MainLoop() 
`
```

Comment: is `smile.png` in the same folder as where you are launching your script from?

Comment: yes it is in the same folder of the script

Comment: and you are launching the script from there? what happens if you try something like `http://www.thinkstockphotos.com/CMS/StaticContent/WhyThinkstockImages/Creative.jpg` instead?  (I use wx2.8 so not sure how much help I can be since it does not have wx.html2)

Comment: same thing it is not show images..while i can do any thing else like css formatting  and javascript ..and I tried to upload the same code as html file on some server and load with loadURL method and it works fine..just cant do it with setPage method

Comment: I would add an alt="pic goes here" within your img tag, to  see where the picture would go if it could be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this code and it is realy not show image from local source but when try some thing like src='http//localhost/smile.png' it is just working and i can view the image successfully..can not find the reason why not read images from the same html folder

Comment: this answer is more suited to be a comment. If you are troubled, please ask a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)